# Property referring to a common interface for two Blocks

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I have a class `Request` that should have a Callback-block property, lets call it `RequestCallback`.

The request itself shouldn't be used, but it has two subclasses. `APIRequest` and `HttpRequest`. (yes, in this case there is a difference).

The callback blocks are different for `APIRequest` and `HttpRequest`, lets call them `APIRequestCallback` and `HttpRequestCallback`.

Block definitions:

```
typedef void (^HttpRequestCallback)(HttpResponse *);
typedef void (^APIRequestCallback)(APIResponse *);
```

I haven't found any way to let my Request class have one Callback property, which can be of either `APIRequestCallback` or `HttpRequestCallback` type.

I can think of ways this can be done, but I haven't seen anything implying it. Examples would be storing my Callback object as `id`, Letting `APIRequestCallback` and `HttpRequestCallback` extend a defined `RequestCallback` etc.

```
// Can be either HttpRequestCallback or APIRequestCallback
@property (copy) RequestCallback callback;
// or
@property (strong) id callback;
// or
@property (strong) id <RequestCallback> callback;
```

Does some skilled objective C developer have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution that pleases me for now. If someone knows better, please educate me.

The `Request` class uses the following Block typedef:

```
typedef void (^RequestCallback)(id);
```

And uses a property like this:

```
@property (copy) RequestCallback callback;
```

This works because the id type doesn't distinguish between `APIResponse` objects and `HttpResponse` objects. I would love to use Objective C's new Generics syntax to force the type to be a __covariant of `Response` but I couldn't get it to work.